# the name 'decrypt' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this class 'IdentityConfig.cs and Helper.cs', On IdentityConfig i am calling Helper class to access Decrypt method with its argument list. Somehow i dont seem to get this and i am getting an error called Decrypt does not exist or am i missing some directive. How do i fix this issue and calling the correct package. Please help me mates to resolve this issue.

```
// IdentityConfig.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System.Net.Mail;
using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Net;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration.App_Start
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Gcobani Mkontwana <ggcobani@gmail.com>");
            mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = message.Body;
            using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
                    Password = Helper.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserPasswd"])
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}

    // Helper class
       using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Helper
{
    public class Helper
    {
        private const string PassPhrase = "3pAc0j$_56K?_S7c9gS!";

        //Encrypt password.
        public static string Encrypt(string strValue)
        {
            byte[] results;
            UTF8Encoding uTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] deskey = md5.ComputeHash(uTF8.GetBytes(PassPhrase));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            desalg.Key = deskey;
            desalg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            desalg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] encrypt_data = uTF8.GetBytes(strValue);

            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform encrytor = desalg.CreateEncryptor();
                results = encrytor.TransformFinalBlock(encrypt_data, 0, encrypt_data.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                desalg.Clear();
                md5.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(results);
        }

        //Decrypt password.

        public static string Decrypt(string strValue)
        {
            byte[] results;
            UTF8Encoding uTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] deskey = md5.ComputeHash(uTF8.GetBytes(PassPhrase));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            desalg.Key = deskey;
            desalg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            desalg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] decrypt_data = Convert.FromBase64String(strValue);
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = desalg.CreateDecryptor();
                results = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(decrypt_data, 0, decrypt_data.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                desalg.Clear();
                md5.Clear();
            }
            return uTF8.GetString(results);
        }

        // In between space
        public static string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
        {
            int Start, End;
            if(strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
            {
                Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
                End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        public static string BytesToString(long byteCount)
        {
            string[] suf = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };
            if (byteCount == 0)
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", 0, suf[0]);
            long bytes = Math.Abs(byteCount);
            int place = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, 1024)));
            double num = Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(1024, place), 1);
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", (Math.Sign(byteCount) * num).ToString(), suf[place]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Helper class is static? Show all atributes of this class.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are missing `using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Helper;`.

Comment: I have that already, still cant access the decrypt method. What am i missing?

Comment: I even add and remove dll files from bin folder, clean and rebuild it. Still the issue does exist so im confused now.

Comment: Well do not know wether if i have solved the problem of this error, basically i took out this namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Helper(this out). See below my work around.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration
{
    public class Helper_b
    {
        private const string PassPhrase = "3pAc0j$_56K?_S7c9gS!";

        //Encrypt password.
        public static string Encrypt(string strValue)
        {
            byte[] results;
            UTF8Encoding uTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] deskey = md5.ComputeHash(uTF8.GetBytes(PassPhrase));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            desalg.Key = deskey;
            desalg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            desalg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] encrypt_data = uTF8.GetBytes(strValue);

            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform encrytor = desalg.CreateEncryptor();
                results = encrytor.TransformFinalBlock(encrypt_data, 0, encrypt_data.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                desalg.Clear();
                md5.Clear();
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(results);
        }

        //Decrypt password.

        public static string Decrypt(string strValue)
        {
            byte[] results;
            UTF8Encoding uTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] deskey = md5.ComputeHash(uTF8.GetBytes(PassPhrase));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider desalg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            desalg.Key = deskey;
            desalg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            desalg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            byte[] decrypt_data = Convert.FromBase64String(strValue);
            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = desalg.CreateDecryptor();
                results = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(decrypt_data, 0, decrypt_data.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                desalg.Clear();
                md5.Clear();
            }
            return uTF8.GetString(results);
        }

        // In between space
        public static string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
        {
            int Start, End;
            if(strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
            {
                Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
                End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        public static string BytesToString(long byteCount)
        {
            string[] suf = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB" };
            if (byteCount == 0)
                return string.Format("{0} {1}", 0, suf[0]);
            long bytes = Math.Abs(byteCount);
            int place = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Math.Log(bytes, 1024)));
            double num = Math.Round(bytes / Math.Pow(1024, place), 1);
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", (Math.Sign(byteCount) * num).ToString(), suf[place]);
        }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using eNtsaTrainingRegistration.Models;
using System.Net.Mail;

using System.Net;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace eNtsaTrainingRegistration
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Gcobani Mkontwana <ggcobani@gmail.com>");
            mailMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = message.Body;

            using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"],
                    Password = Helper_b.Decrypt(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserPassword"])
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPName"];
                smtp.Port = int.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPort"]);
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
            }
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        } 
        }

    }
```